# DT shiny R tooltip and hide column

Tags: javascript, css, r, shiny, dt

I'm trying to do two things on a DT data table in shiny R.

My code (example from github) is the following:

```
library("shiny")
library("shinydashboard")
library("datasets")
library("DT")

header <- dashboardHeader()

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()

body <- dashboardBody(
  DT::dataTableOutput("mtcarsTable")
)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body),
  server = function(input, output) {

    output$mtcarsTable <- renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(datasets::mtcars, 
                    options = list(rowCallback = JS('
                                                    function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
                                                    // Bold and green cells for conditions
                                                    if (parseFloat(aData[4]) >= 200)
                                                    $("td:eq(3)", nRow).css("font-weight", "bold");
                                                    if (parseFloat(aData[4]) >= 100)
                                                    $("td:eq(3)", nRow).css("background-color", "#9BF59B");
                                                    }')
                      )
                    )
  })
  }
                    )
```

As you can see I'm evaluating column 4, to give to a cell a background color as also as to define if it should be bold or not.

Is it possible to hide column 4? I just want to evaluate it, I don't want it to be shown.

My other question is if it is possible to add a tool tip only to the cells with green background? I saw that I should use the callback but I don't know how and I'm not an expert at javascript.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: To hide column 4 you can use `datasets::mtcars[,-3]` instead of `datasets::mtcars`

Comment: I was able to hide columns with columnDefs = list(list(targets = 4, visible=FALSE)). The columns that I wanted to hide had to be placed after the columns that I wanted to be visible for the JS to successfully apply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible to add a tool tip only to the cells with green background. We have to use javascript  below:

```
DT::datatable(datasets::mtcars, 
              options = list(rowCallback = JS(
                "function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {",
                "// Bold and green cells for conditions",
                "if (parseFloat(aData[4]) >= 200)",
                "$('td:eq(3)', nRow).css('font-weight', 'bold');",
                "if (parseFloat(aData[4]) >= 100){",
                "$('td:eq(3)', nRow).css('background-color', '#9BF59B');",
                "var full_text = aData[3]",
                "$('td:eq(3)', nRow).attr('title', full_text);",
                "}",
                "}")
              )
)
```

**[EDIT]:**

To add formattings to the tooltip I have added few more lines and it only works in shinyApp and not DT datatable. See the code below:

```
header <- dashboardHeader()

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()

body <- dashboardBody(
  DT::dataTableOutput("mtcarsTable")
)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body),
  server = function(input, output) {

    output$mtcarsTable <- renderDataTable({
      DT::datatable(datasets::mtcars, 
                    options = list(rowCallback = JS(
                      "function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {",
                      "// Bold and green cells for conditions",
                      "if (parseFloat(aData[4]) >= 200)",
                      "$('td:eq(3)', nRow).css('font-weight', 'bold');",
                      "if (parseFloat(aData[4]) >= 100){",
                      "$('td:eq(3)', nRow).css('background-color', '#9BF59B');",
                      "var full_text = aData[3]",
                      "$('td:eq(3)', nRow).attr('title', full_text);",
                      "//Code for formatting tooltip",
                      "$('td:eq(3)', nRow).tooltip({",
                        "'delay': 0,",
                        "'track': true,",
                        "'fade': 250,",
                      "});",


                      "}",
                      "}")
                    )
      )

    })
  }
)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @SBiasta Is there any way of editing the tooltip box?

Comment: Do you want to edit the text in the tooltip? To do that you can change the `var full_text = aData[3]` to `var full_text ='The text you want'`

Comment: @SBiasta no, I mean the window. Can I edit size, colors,...? There is any documentation about this?

Comment: Yes, I think it is possible to change the size, colours using css. This [link](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) suggests that you can change the tooltip attribute.

Comment: @SBiasta ok, it seems to be what I want, but how can I add this html and css function inside the datatable R function?

Comment: @hsilva I have edited the code with formatting for tooltip. Hope it helps!

Comment: @hsilva You can refer this [link](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/25868/using-tooltips-with-datatables#Comment_70938) for reference.

Comment: @SBiasta Have you noticed that when you hover on a green cell, the right side cell moves 1 column?

Comment: @hsilva I just noticed that but not able to figure out why. Will look more into it and see if there is a solution to that.